# SharePoint Server Search - Internal Server Error when searching

Tags: search, error, fast-search

I presently have two Search Service Applications configured, correctly, on the farm.  One is for routine searching of SharePoint whereas the other is for our enterprise searching via FAST.  In either case, I find myself needing to recycle the application pools for all related app pools including the one for the security token web service.  I am considering configuring the app pools to all recycle at 5:50 AM with a timeout of 1440 minutes.  My reservation is that I am worried that I may be missing something.  Does anyone else have a similiar sitution?

This [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao1/archive/2011/03/15/sharepoint-2010-search-internal-server-error-exception-system-nullreferenceexception.aspx) is informative, but, ultimately, their workaround is unneeded on my farm.

**UPDATE 1:**

I am still getting this error each morning.

Now after likely 50-100 refreshes, the search started working on both the FAST and SP Search sites.

Here is the latest error I got when I got a random Internal Server Error.  Please note, the same search worked after a refresh (again):

```
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47  w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '                Runtime Error                     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}           b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}           H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }           H2... 53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        ... { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }           pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}           .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}           .version {color: gray;}           .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}           .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }                                        Server Error in '/167616a788604bc1b3254c26618dbcf8' Application.                 Runtime'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactor...   53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        ...y.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, Ti...  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        ...meSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchS...  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        ...erviceApplicationProxy.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(ISearchServiceApplication serviceApplication)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)   53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47  w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (SharePointSearchRuntime::GetQueryResult). Execution Time=188.164976274918  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47  w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        Exception when fetching results: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '                Runtime Error                     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}           b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}           H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }           H2 { font-family:"Verdan... 53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        ...a";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }           pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}           .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}           .version {color: gray;}           .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}           .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }                                        Server Error in '/167616a788604bc1b3254c26618dbcf8' Application.                 Runtime'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.H...   53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        ...ttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at...  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        ... System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy...  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        ....c__DisplayClass4.b__3(ISearchServiceApplication serviceApplication)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRun...  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
05/11/2011 10:47:21.47* w3wp.exe (0x111C)                           0x095C  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dlr1    High        ...time.GetQueryResult(String query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SharePointSearchRuntime.SendRequest(String query)  53c659e1-ba6a-4cf9-b9ee-95e6bf94e692
```

Comment: Neven seen the error, but why don't you index all content in FAST?

Comment: Not every web application will use the FAST SSA.

Comment: Have you checked the sharepoint logs for any errors?

Comment: I have consulted the logs, and I am not getting a consistent message. Sometimes the logs report a Null result, other times it is a SOAP error.  I pasted the latest error I received while doing a SP Search, not FAST.

Comment: Added a full post of the latest log.  I get this error every so often when the web service fails.

Comment: The issue seems to be when the client is unable to pass the query to the actual query processor, which I believe leverages the SharePoint Web Services Default/System app pools.

Comment: Can you try and move your oob content sources over to the FAST Query SSA. The FAST Query SSA is an "default search" in disguise, and if you set your target location to "Local SharePoint sites" and have the FAST Query SSA as your default Search SSA, then it will act the part perfectly.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer (or workaround) for this that you can provide?

Comment: I have to recycle the App Pools daily to get traditional search working.  There is some refiner in FAST that is "missing", which we are able to remove on the enterprise search page, but causes issues on site searching.  I'll looking into this suggestion and see if I can help our FAST admin with figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with MSS Search, but it happened all the time when searching from the local farm but worked fine when searching from other farms that connected to the SSA.

I noticed that the SSA Proxy was not indented underneath the SSA. It was at the bottom by itself. I have no clue how it got there.

I used PS to remove and recreate the proxy (assumes you only have 1 SSA):

```
$p = get-spenterprisesearchserviceapplicationproxy
remove-spenterprisesearchserviceapplicationproxy $p

$sa = get-spenterprisesearchserviceapplication
$pn = [string]($sa | Select -ExpandProperty Name) + " Proxy"
new-spenterprisesearchserviceapplicationproxy -name $pn -searchapplication $sa
```

I ran IISRESET.

All my issues were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not consider the following as the answer as it fixes the issue temporarily and after some time the same error appears.

Temp Fix:

Do IISRESET

If anyone has a permanent fix to this, please do help.